# Eigenvectors of Kronecker Product

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory, eigenvector

**Conjecture** If $A$ and $B$ are two complex square matrices, then every eigenvector of $A\otimes B$ is of the form $x\otimes y$, where $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $y$ is an eigenvector of $B$.

Here, $A\otimes B$ denotes the [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of two matrices. I would like to know if this conjecture is true.

**Motivation:** I know that the following is true:

**Theorem**
Let $A$ and $B$ be two complex square matrices. If $\lambda$ is
an eigenvalue of $A$ with corresponding eigenvector $x$ and $\mu$
is an eigenvector of $B$ with corresponding eigenvector $y$, then
$\lambda\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A\otimes B$ with corresponding
eigenvector $x\otimes y$. Moreover, every eigenvalue of $A\otimes B$
arises as such a product.

This is Theorem 4.2.12 in Horn and Johnson's "Topics in Matrix Analysis'',
or Theorem 13.12 [here](https://archive.siam.org/books/textbooks/OT91sample.pdf).
However, no statement is made that all eigenvectors arise in such
fashion. Does the conjecture follow from this theorem?

Comment: In the nondiagonalizable case, it's not even true that all eigenvectors lie in the span of products of eigenvectors. Take $A$ and $B$ to be the $2$-by-$2$ Jordan block with eigenvalue $1$. Then $e_1\otimes e_1$ and $e_1\otimes e_2-e_2\otimes e_1$ are both eigenvectors of $A\otimes B$. The problem of computing the extra eigenvectors can always be reduced to the case where $A$ and $B$ are Jordan blocks by Jordanizing both.

Comment: Thanks @MTyson! This is actually closer to what I had in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Counterexample: the matrix $I \times I$ has eigenvectors that are not in product form, since every vector is an eigenvector of it and not every vector can be written in product form.

Comment: Ha! Good point. Now I feel silly. I'll see if there is a different way of phrasing the question...

Comment: if both matrices are diagonalizable, their tensor product does have a basis of eigenvectors of the form you indicate